Basic index strategy for SQL Server table
Say I have a table that contains the forecasted temperature for each day of the next 10 years, and I recalculate these forecasts every day.
Forecast table:



ID
DateCalculated
CalendarDay
LocationId
Temperature




999
1/5/2024
9/10/2033
55
98


998
1/5/2024
9/6/2033
55
99


997
1/5/2024
9/5/2033
55
102


996
1/5/2024
9/4/2033
55
98


...
...
...
...
...


400
1/4/2024
9/6/2033
55
97


399
1/4/2024
9/5/2033
55
99


398
1/4/2024
9/3/2033
55
102


397
1/4/2024
9/2/2033
55
97



Note: there are gaps between calendar days, sometimes recalculating a day fails so we don't save it.
If my only objective with this data is to be able to provide the most recently (ostensibly the most accurate) calculated temperature for a particular location/day, what's the correct approach for creating my clustered index?
Is a clustered index with DateCalculated desc, CalendarDay desc, LocationId desc the right approach?
Example query:
select top 1
    Temperature 
from
    Forecasts
where 
    LocationId = 55 and CalendarDay = '1/7/2025'
order by 
    DateCalculated desc

Reading the Microsoft documentation it mentions clustered indexes aren't a good choice for Wide keys which it defines as:

Wide keys are a composite of several columns or several large-size columns [...]

I can't quite tell if my proposed composite key of DateCalculated, CalendarDay, LocationId would be considered a wide key.

If you are looking to retrieve the last calculated temperature for a particular day & location, I would look at an index based upon locationId, calendar day and date calculated desc. A date datatype is 3 bytes long so the total size of the index is 3+4+3 = 10.

Anything more than 2 weeks out is pure fantasy :(

Tell me these are actually date columns, and not varchar? Because 1/7/2025 is wrong for date literals in SQL, and if you're storing these dates as varchar than any indexes will be practically worthless, especially for sorting.

They are indeed date columns! I tried my best formatting things for SO - some details were lost along the way though. Technically the real data is forecasting pricing/commodities but I figured location/temperatures was an easier way to convey the problem

No, it's a bad index, but not because of wide keys. It's not that wide, and if it's necessary for the query then it's necessary. A wide key would be many many bytes, over 32 bytes is one possible rule of thumb.
The problem is that this index is not going to help you. You need to put the equiality predicate columns first, then the inequality/join/sorting column(s).
The best index is going to be either:
(LocationId, CalendarDay, DateCalculated DESC) INCLUDE (Temperature)

Or:
(CalendarDay, LocationId, DateCalculated DESC) INCLUDE (Temperature)

So the first two columns can be in either order (and either ascending or descending), although you may want to look at what other queries need, as they may use one of those columns as an inequality or join predicate, or as a sorting column.
Also note the addition of INCLUDE so that you don't need a key lookup for the Temperature column. Consider making this index a clustered index, then all other columns are automatically included. You could even make these three columns the primary key and remove the unnecessary Id column.

Ah okay that makes sense. I was wondering about how to avoid a secondary lookup to get the temperature, but not including it in the index - INCLUDE is perfect. I'll probably go with making it a clustered index like you suggested so I may not need INCLUDE, but it's good to know for the future. Thank you!
